# "ImportError: No module named serial" - after installing pyserial

Tags: python, windows

I'm writing a project in python which should eventually running on LinkIt One IoT device.

I've written some test code to check whether I am able to connect between Arduino IDE to python (I am working with Pycharm).

the test code is:

```
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial('COM1', 115200, timeout=.1)

time.sleep(1) #give the connection a second to settle

arduino.write("Hello from Python!")

while True:
    data = arduino.readline()
    if data:
        print data.rstrip('\n')
```

when I am running to code I am getting:

> C:\Users\אורי\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/אורי/PycharmProjects/untitled2/test.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/����/PycharmProjects/untitled2/test.py", line 1, in 
>       import serial
>   ImportError: No module named serial

Comment: You've probably installed pyserial for the wrong python interpreter. Make sure you install it for the interpreter that you are using to run your code with.

Answer (score 4):

how did you install your serial module?
If you want to make sure It will be detected,
go into your console

```
pip install serial
```

and run your code from the console too

```
python test.py # make sure your console is in the right folder path
```

**or**

find where the module is installed, something like "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages") # this is where python stores modules, yours could be different 
import serial
```

Comment: It is ``pyserial`` on PyPi, not ``serial``.

Comment: I haven't really check it, I was moslty focusing on the procedure,"how to do it", so you can do it with any package

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes we mix things up ourselves. But we won't realize that.**

On linux or windows :

- A = Os required Python version(like:64bit or 32Bit, 2.7.x, 3.X.X, etc.)
- B = The version we need.(like:x86 arch, 1.6.X, 2.6.X, 3.0, etc.)
- C = Another version we need(like:X64)

Every IDLE (which is linked to /bin or OS.PATH) work on **native directory** (os never touch this things.). Install a library system-wide but try to call external IDLE or install library locally and call from system-wide.

Which installer (I do not recommend) used system environment variables, but maybe you want install a library locally!

Short answer:

1. Go to your idle directory(what you want(used))
2. Download your module
3. Extract somewhere
4. Use version of Python (which you want, joined dir(1.)) **python /extract-dir/setup.py *kwargs**

Note :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages")
```

Don't do that, because you aren't standard user !

I hope it helps. I'm sorry if you lost time.